# Single column figure leaves a blank in the other column?

Tags: floats, two-column

I am writing in a double-column template (IEEE Conference Template).

What has been bothering me is that once I have a figure/pseudocode/tikz in one column, sometimes it pushes the contents in the other column down, as if it wanted to occupy both columns.

Like so:
[image]

[image]

But in fact it only takes up one column.

Sometimes I can solve this issue by moving the figure snippet around. But it is definitely a method by luck...

What is the formal way of solving this issue?

**My sincere apologies for not providing a MWE. I have tried very hard, but the problem never appears while creating a MWE!**

Comment: Have you tried issuing the instruction `\raggedbottom`?

Comment: @Mico No. Could you please elaborate? Where should I issue that please?

Comment: In the preamble, I'd say.

Comment: @Mico  Just tried, it made no differences. ;(

Answer (score 1):

You should make the figures smaller. There is always a predefined gap between two columns that you cannot exceed. Puting two plots with `0.5\linewidth` side by side will always result in an overflow and the plots will be placed underneath each other. Rather make them `0.495\linewidth` or so.

Comment: better is use `columnwidh`: for example `includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{<image file name>}`